# React Native: How to handle protected routes with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

What I want is to protect specific screens where the user can run specific actions and only at that point redirect him to a login screen, if the user is successfully authenticated, redirect him to the point where he left off the flow.

We can do this in React JS(with react-router), so I would like to know if its posible to implement a similar solution for react-native(with react-navigation):

### React JS approach with React Router

```js
function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const { authed } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();

  return authed === true ? (
    children
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ path: location.pathname }} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in react native and is documented in the [authentication workflow section of the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/).

In summary we conditionally need to render screens inside the navigator. Here is a minimal example using a `Stack.Navigator` which is similar to your posted code snippet. The workflow is identical for other navigators (nested or not). I will use the `context api` in my example, but there are other ways to achieve the same as well. The overall pattern is the same.

```js
const AppContext = React.createContext()

function App() {

  const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = React.useState(false)

  const appContextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      isSignedIn,
      setIsSignedIn,
    }),
    [isSignedIn]
  )
    return (
     <AppContext.Provider value={appContextValue}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {!isSignedIn ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={LoginScreen}
          />
          ) : (
          // whatever screens if user is logged in
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        )}
       </Stack.Navigator>
    </AppContext.Provider>
);
```

In the `LoginScreen`, you then need to change the `authed` state to `true` if the login was successful. The first screen in the conditional will then be initially rendered automatically (in this case `HomeScreen`).

```js
function LoginScreen() {
   const { setIsSignedIn } = useContext(AppContext)

   // do whatever, then setIsSignedIn to true
}
```

Comment: How would you handle the redirection to the screen where the user left the flow?

Comment: That is even simpler. Use the same context object, and guard the specific screens. Then just call `navigation.goBack()` if the login was successful on the LoginScreen.

Comment: How would you handle a logout with this solution? I would imagine a `setIsSignedIn(false)` and `navigation.navigate(Login)`. But in that case it may happen that the route hasn't been created yet, it would be like a race condition.

Comment: You don't navigate in this scenario. The whole stack navigator screen structure is replaced. The context state value `isSignedIn` is set to false -> a state change is triggered in `App` -> re-render of `App` -> initial route of `Stack.Navigator` is `LoginScreen` since `HomeScreen` won't be rendered at all -> `LoginScreen` will be visible to the user. No navigation needed. The same will actually happen for login as well.

Comment: This anwer just adds `LoginScreen` to the navigation stack and does not address the question.

Comment: It does address the question. The LoginScreen is only added to the stack if the user is not authenticated, and adds the other screens otherwise. The user will be redirected to the default routes of the added stack automatically by the navigation framework depending on the state.